# How can I parse a string using bash to get a number

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following string:

```
PR-1769|7bb12d4152a497cef491e0a1088b3984ad92972f|jaga|
```

How can I parse the string above using bash so that I get the `1769`?

Also, how do I get the last string `jaga` using bash?

Comment: what's the pattern you're trying to match ?

Comment: You'll probably need regular expressions.

Comment: its usually PR-NUMBER|STRING|STRING| I need to get the NUMBER

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for `grep` here: bash has built-in regex support, which is *vastly* more efficient to use than starting up an external utility just to process a single line:

```
re='^PR-([0-9]+)'
s='PR-1769|7bb12d4152a497cef491e0a1088b3984ad92972f|marvel|'

if [[ $s =~ $re ]]; then
  echo "Matched: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

---

You can also use parameter expansions:

```
s='PR-1769|7bb12d4152a497cef491e0a1088b3984ad92972f|marvel|'
s="${s%%'|'*}" # trim off everything after the first |
s="${s#PR-}"   # trim off the leading PR
echo "$s"
```

---

If you needed to extract the individual fields, by the way, `read` might be the correct tool for the job:

```
s='PR-1769|7bb12d4152a497cef491e0a1088b3984ad92972f|marvel|'
IFS='|' read -r pr hash username <<<"$s"
```

...the above will put `PR-1769` into the variable `pr`, `7bb12d4152a497cef491e0a1088b3984ad92972f` into the variable `hash`, and `marvel` into the variable `username`. To strip off the `PR-`, then, might simply look like:

```
echo "${pr#PR-}"
```

...or, to print the extracted username:

```
echo "$username"
```

---

See:

- [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) ("How do I do string manipulations in bash?")
- [bash-hackers.org parameter expansion reference](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: Note as well that both the parameter expansion and `read` methods work in (non-bash) POSIX shells, although the `read` method requires a here document rather than bash's triple-`<` form.

Answer (score 0):

Based on posted,

by using `grep`

```
echo 'PR-1769|7bb12d4152a497cef491e0a1088b3984ad92972f|marvel|' | grep -Po "(PR-)([0-9]+)" | grep -Po "[0-9]+"
```

1. the string is being echoed and redirected to grep for the first time
2. in first iteration grep is extracting and outputting `PR-1769`
3. `PR-1769` is in second iteration redirected to grep again, now `1769` is extracted and outputted

---

This is only first-shot version of solution, some grep regex expert would certainly know how to do it with single grep call.

It will only give you result if echoed string is in **PR-NUMBER** format, as you have presented.

Comment: type `grep --version` and tell me the grep version

Comment: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: ...why do you need `-P`? These are strictly ERE-compatible regexes. (Not that I'd advise using `grep` here at all).

Comment: I have also found this to be strange. But certainly it is not working without `-P`

Comment: It needs `-E` to specify ERE, because otherwise you have BRE syntax, which doesn't support `+` in the way you expect, but you don't need `-P`.

Comment: ...a bigger problem, though, is that `-o` is itself a non-POSIX extension, and not available on all platforms; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html

Comment: ...see `grep -Eo "(PR-)([0-9]+)"`, and you'll see that works anywhere `grep -P` does... though you still have your portability issues due to the dependency on `-o`.

Comment: ...and btw, while you can do this in a single `grep` invocation if you have PCRE extensions (`-P`), BRE or ERE doesn't support lookbehind assertions, so it's not possible with either of the POSIX-compliant forms.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy tnx for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using awk:

```
echo 'PR-1769|7bb12d4152a497cef491e0a1088b3984ad92972f|jaga|'|awk -F'|' '{print substr($1, 4)}'
```