# How to get second string using bash

Tags: bash

How do I get the second string in

```
TE-2025|2bc80a34b83d11289a352f7d8a2e47204c283b4f|test|
```

using bash?

that is 2bc80a34b83d11289a352f7d8a2e47204c283b4f

This is not a duplicate. I want to get the second string not the first!

Comment: Where's the data stored? In a file?  In a string variable?  IFS may be part of the answer — or fancy options to `read`.  Or you can use `cut`, `awk`, `sed`, `perl`, `python`, … or [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) with the substitute variations.

Comment: I could swear I've answered this exact question already.

Comment: Ahh -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927646/how-can-i-parse-a-string-using-bash-to-get-a-number -- very slightly different question about the same data (and data format), but my answer there *does* describe how to perform the exact operation requested here.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS='|' read -r first second _ <<<'PR-2025|2bc80a34b83d11289a352f7d8a2e47204c283b4f|test|'
echo "$second"
```